# Without using absolute div, can we create different layered overlapping divs

Tags: html, css

I need help to create the following view. I can definitely use position absolute but is there a way to do it without using the absolute value?

[image]

Comment: You can use `z-index` and `left/right` css properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.balls {
  display: flex;
}

.balls>.left {
  height: 2.3rem;
  width: 2.4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: -0.9rem;
  border: 4px solid white;
  background-color: red;
}

.center_ball {
  z-index: 99999;
}

.left_ball2 {
  z-index: 9999;
}

.right_ball2 {
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="balls">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left left_ball2"></div>
  <div class="left center_ball"></div>
  <div class="left right_ball2"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use this it will give you perfect as you want like Image

Comment: perfect @Lucifer ! 

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this? Adding a `display: flex` to make them stay on the same row, and a negative `margin` to make them override each other.

```css
.balls {
  display: flex;
  }

.balls > .left {
  height: 2.3rem;
  width: 2.4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: -0.9rem;
  border: 4px solid white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="balls">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="left"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: But the center ball needs to be at the top for 2nd and 4th ball and 5th ball should be below 4th.

Comment: check Lucifer's answer, he corrected my code @Skaranjit

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a snippet with live example

```css
.first {
    z-index: 1;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    position: relative;
}

.second {
    z-index: 2;
    left: -60px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.third {
    z-index: 1;
    left: -100px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <img src="https://fr.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia-wordmark-fr.svg" class="first">
   
   <img src="https://fr.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia-wordmark-fr.svg" class="second">
   
   <img src="https://fr.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia-wordmark-fr.svg" class="third">
</div>
```